# $zero - O que faz e como funciona?

Tags: assembly

Boas! Comecei a estudar à pouco assembly para o MIPS. Alguém consegue-me explicar como funciona esta linha de código, ld r4,A(r0), onde o r0 tem o mesmo significado de $zero?

```
.data

A:  .word 10
B:  .word 8
C:  .word 0

.text
main:
        ld r4,A(r0)
        ld r5,B(r0)
        dadd r3, r4, r5
        sd r3,C(r0)
        halt
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo tipo de instruções utilizadas (`ld` e `dadd`), acredito que isto é MIPS-64 ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063669/the-difference-between-add-and-dadd) que diz que o `dadd` está presente no MIPS-64).

Não tenho experiência com o MIPS-64 e trabalhei pouco com o Assembly MIPS-32, mas isto é a minha leitura do código:

`ld` é `load` (de 64 bits) e `dadd` é `signed add` (de 64 bits).

Este código começa por declarar três variáveis: A, B e C com os valores iniciais `10`, `8` e `0`. Essas variáveis são declaradas com o tamanho de uma word. Não tenho a certeza se isso são 32 ou 64 bits, mas o código que se segue só faz sentido se forem de 64 bits.

Leituras do registo `$zero` (`r0`) dão o valor `0` e escritas neste registo são ignoradas.
`ld X, Y(Z)` carrega no registo `X` o valor na posição `Y + Z` (isto dá jeito quando se estão a fazer acessos a índices constantes de arrays). Visto que `Z` é zero, carrega a posição diretamente.

O que isto faz é:

1. Carregar a variável global A no registo `r4`.
2. Carregar a variável global B no registo `r5`.
3. Somar as duas variáveis e guardar o resultado em `r3`.
4. Guardar o valor em `r3` na variável global C.
5. Parar a execução.

Ou seja, `C = A + B`. Portanto, C acaba com o valor `18`.

O código C equivalente é:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t A, B, C;

int main()
{
    C = A + B;
    // Ou o seguinte, que é equivalente:
    // (&C)[0] = (&A)[0] + (&B)[0];

    halt(); // Talvez implementado como for (;;) {}
            // Embora imagino que o halt seja mais eficiente
}
```